# Unable to print the report generated with reportlab in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, reportlab, printers

I have created a customer sale report with reportlab, the report is being generated successfully and when I press the print button, it is being saved in the pdf format, when the external printer is not connect it show error the no printer is connected and gets saved, but when I connect the printer and then press print button, then it does not show error, and gets saved in pdf but does not gets printed.

here is my code for the report

```py
def print_cutomer_bill(self, data, code, id):
        
             pdf_bill = str(code)+".pdf"


             #    insert sale_record into database
             cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_sale (customer_id, bill_code, total_amount, discount, previous_amount, amount_paid, amount_remaining, return_amount, sale_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (id, code, self.cr_bill, self.discount, self.pre_balance, self.cash, self.total_remains, self.return_amount, self.cr_date))

             
             sale_id = cursor.lastrowid
             page_height = 1000

             c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_bill, pagesize=(600,1000))
             
             c.setFont("Helvetica", 15)
             c.drawString(200, page_height - 20, "HAZRAT CLOTH HOUSE")

             c.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 50, f"Address: Rangpur Adda, Rangpur Road")
             c.drawString(350, page_height - 50, f"Contact: 03459236354, 03463868838")
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 60, "_" * 80)
        

     #     bill header
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 80, f"Invoice No. {code}")
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 100, f"Fullname: {data[0]}")
             c.drawString(220, page_height - 100, f"Phone No. : {data[3]}")
             c.drawString(420, page_height - 100, f"Address: {data[4]}")
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 120, f"Date: {self.cr_date}")

     #     draw line
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 140, "_" * 80)
          # headers
             c.drawString(40, page_height - 180, "SNo.")
             c.drawString(100, page_height - 180, "Name")
             c.drawString(280, page_height - 180, "Qty")
             c.drawString(350, page_height - 180, "Price")
             c.drawString(420, page_height - 180, "Total")

             y_position = page_height -200
             s_no = 1
             for rows in self.product_rows:
                    prodid = self.product_rows[rows]["id"].get()
                    
                    if prodid:
                         quantity = self.product_rows[rows]["quantity"].get()
                         name = self.product_rows[rows]["name"].get()
                         price = float(self.product_rows[rows]["price"].get())
                         total = float(self.product_rows[rows]["total"].get())
                         c.drawString(50, y_position, str(s_no))
                         c.drawString(110, y_position, name)
                         c.drawString(290, y_position, quantity)
                         c.drawString(360, y_position, str(int(price // 1)))
                         c.drawString(430, y_position, str(int(total // 1)))

               #     for borders
                         c.rect(40, y_position - 5, 60, 20)  # SNo. column
                         c.rect(100, y_position - 5, 180, 20)  # Name column
                         c.rect(280, y_position - 5, 70, 20)  # Qty column
                         c.rect(350, y_position - 5, 70, 20)  # Price column
                         c.rect(420, y_position - 5, 80, 20)  # Total column

                         y_position -= 20
                         s_no = int(s_no) + 1


                         # insert into sale detail
                         #    insert sale_record into database
                         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_sale_detail (sale_id, product_id, purchased_units, product_price, subtotal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (sale_id, prodid, quantity, price, total))

                         # update product quantity
                         cursor.execute("SELECT stock FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id=?",(prodid,))
                         qty = cursor.fetchone()
                         stock = qty[0] - int(quantity)

                         cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_product SET stock=? WHERE product_id=?",(stock, prodid,))
        
             c.drawString(40, y_position - 50, "****** WAPSI ******")
             c.drawString(40, y_position - 60, "_" * 80)

             y_position = y_position - 100
             s_no = 1
             for rows in self.product_return_rows:
                    pro_ret_id = self.product_return_rows[rows]["id"].get()
                    
                    if pro_ret_id:
                         quantity = self.product_return_rows[rows]["quantity"].get()
                         name = self.product_return_rows[rows]["name"].get()
                         price = float(self.product_return_rows[rows]["price"].get())
                         total = float(self.product_return_rows[rows]["total"].get())

                         c.drawString(50, y_position, str(s_no))
                         c.drawString(110, y_position, name)
                         c.drawString(290, y_position, quantity)
                         c.drawString(360, y_position, str(int(price // 1)))
                         c.drawString(430, y_position, str(int(total // 1)))

               #     for borders
                         c.rect(40, y_position - 5, 60, 20)  # SNo. column
                         c.rect(100, y_position - 5, 180, 20)  # Name column
                         c.rect(280, y_position - 5, 70, 20)  # Qty column
                         c.rect(350, y_position - 5, 70, 20)  # Price column
                         c.rect(420, y_position - 5, 80, 20)  # Total column

                         y_position -= 20
                         s_no = int(s_no) + 1


                         # insert into return detail
                         #    insert sale_record into database
                         cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_return (sale_id, product_id, return_units, product_price, subtotal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (sale_id, pro_ret_id, quantity, price, total))

                         # update product quantity
                         cursor.execute("SELECT stock FROM tbl_product WHERE product_id=?",(pro_ret_id,))
                         qty = cursor.fetchone()
                         stock = qty[0] + int(quantity)

                         cursor.execute("UPDATE tbl_product SET stock=? WHERE product_id=?",(stock, pro_ret_id,))

             conn.commit()
             y_position = y_position - 20

             c.drawString(40, y_position - 10, f"Cr-Bill: {str(int(self.cr_bill // 1))}")
             c.drawString(220, y_position - 10, f"Discount. : {str(int(self.discount // 1))}")
             c.drawString(420, y_position - 10, f"Pre-Balance: {str(int(self.pre_balance // 1))}")

             c.drawString(40, y_position - 30, f"Return: {str(int(self.return_amount // 1))}")
             c.drawString(220, y_position - 30, f"Cash. : {str(int(self.cash // 1))}")
             c.drawString(420, y_position - 30, f"Due Balance: {str(int(self.total_remains // 1))}")
             

             c.drawString(40, y_position - 100, "_" * 80)
             c.drawString(40, y_position - 120, "Developed By: www.easywebsols.com")

             try:
                    c.save()
                    os.startfile(pdf_bill,'Print')
             except OSError as e:
                  if e.winerror == 1155:
                       
                       messagebox.showerror("Printer Error","No printer is available or connected!")
                  else:
                       messagebox.showerror("Error",f"An error occured while trying to print: {str(e)}")
             else:
               messagebox.showinfo("SUCCESS","Bill Saved Successfully")
```

Is there any problem with my code or compatibility issue with version of reportlab,
I am using window 11, latest version of python and reportlab

Comment: @KJ but I want to be able to print directly from this code instead of previewing the file in acrobat or browser. Isn't there any way to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain how can I get this done with code.
While I  am able to print the reports from browser but I don't want to use a second application to print the pdf file